# How to limit the boundary of pan in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to limit the boundary of pan in fabric js?

I wrote the following code to limit the pan of my canvas but it is just not working. I want it to remember how much it has move outside of the canvas so that even after your pointer goes out of the canvas, you will have to move back the same amount to start dragging again. Currently, after the pointer move out of the canvas, the image will stick it. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?

***Update***
The following solution seems to work for zoom 1x. Still need to figure out how to solve it after zoom. But it is so verbose. Is there a better way to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/yxchng/0hL2khro/356/

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
    if (this.isDragging) {

    var e = opt.e;
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    var moveX = 0;
    var moveY = 0;


    if ((e.clientX - this.lastPosX) * this.offsetX > 0) {
        this.offsetX += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
    } else if (e.clientX - this.lastPosX > 0 && this.offsetX < 0) {
        moveX = e.clientX - this.lastPosX + this.offsetX;
        if (moveX > 0) {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += moveX;
        this.offsetX = 0;
      } else {
        this.offsetX = moveX;
      }
    } else if (e.clientX - this.lastPosX < 0  && this.offsetX > 0) {
        moveX = e.clientX - this.lastPosX + this.offsetX;
        if (moveX < 0) {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += moveX;
        this.offsetX = 0;
      } else {
        this.offsetX = moveX;
      }
    } else {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
      if (this.viewportTransform[4] < 0) {
        this.offsetX = this.viewportTransform[4];
        this.viewportTransform[4] = 0;
      } 
      if (this.viewportTransform[4] > canvas.width) {
        this.offsetX = this.viewportTransform[4] - canvas.width;
        this.viewportTransform[4] = canvas.width;
      } 
    }

    if ((e.clientY - this.lastPosY) * this.offsetY > 0) {
        this.offsetY += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
    } else if (e.clientY - this.lastPosY > 0 && this.offsetY < 0) {
        moveY = e.clientY - this.lastPosY + this.offsetY;
        if (moveY > 0) {
        this.viewportTransform[5] += moveY;
        this.offsetY = 0;
      } else {
        this.offsetY = moveY;
      }
    } else if (e.clientY - this.lastPosY < 0  && this.offsetY > 0) {
        moveY = e.clientY - this.lastPosY + this.offsetY;
        if (moveY < 0) {
        this.viewportTransform[5] += moveY;
        this.offsetY = 0;
      } else {
        this.offsetY = moveY;
      }
    } else {
        this.viewportTransform[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
      if (this.viewportTransform[5] < 0) {
        this.offsetY = this.viewportTransform[5];
        this.viewportTransform[5] = 0;
      } 
      if (this.viewportTransform[5] > canvas.height) {
        this.offsetY = this.viewportTransform[5] - canvas.height;
        this.viewportTransform[5] = canvas.height;
      } 
    }

    this.requestRenderAll();
    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
  }
});
```